# I need to save a CSV file using selenium and Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, selenium, cucumber

I'm struggling with a feature.

I have a scenario where I click a hyperlink to download a CSV. I have the command to open the csv file sorted.  Once that hyperlink is pressed, a pop up box shows up in Firefox and I need to select the Save File option then press OK.

I have no idea how to tell selenium to do this.  I have a test code to confirm a new webpage has opened (below)

```
new_window=page.driver.browser.window_handles.last 
   page.within_window new_window do
     current_url.should eql "https://...."
end
```

This approach doesn't work for the download pop up. I need to move to the pop up and press those two options.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This might help you http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/ or http://www.browserstack.com/automate/ruby#enhancements-uploads-downloads

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one important thing: Once your hyperlink is pressed, **Firefox directs the underlying operating system** to launch a pop up. In other words, you are no longer dealing with Firefox, and therefore Selenium is completely blind to that modal window. Generally the solution is something like Sikuli, Robot, or some other framework.

Also, have a read through this: http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/